# Next.js read Local Excel File and display as a table

Tags: reactjs, excel, next.js

I want to read an excel file inside my Next.js application. The excel file is located in my root directory of the project.

I didn't find any good answer about reading excel files in Next.js and display them as a table. So I wanted to ask, if any of you has any idea how this works?

I tried this which didn't work:

`` `import styles from "./index.module.css" ``
`import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';`
`import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';`

`export default function IndexPage() {`

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (evt) => { // evt = on_file_select event
    /* Parse data */
    const bstr = evt.target.result;
    const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:'binary'});

    /* Get first worksheet */
    const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
    const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];

    /* Convert array of arrays */
    const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(ws, {header:1});

    /* Update state */
    console.log("Data>>>"+data);
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(f);

// render the data as a table
return (
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Pair</th>
            <th>Win / Loss in %</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {data.map((row, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
                <td>{row[0]}</td>
                <td>{row[1]}</td>
            </tr>
        ))}
        </tbody>
    </table>
);`` }` ``
```

Does someone know, how I can approach on this problem or even better do you have a solution?

Import Excel file, read it and display the data in Excel.